# What is a Kubernetes client-go "clientset"?

Tags: go, kubernetes

In the kubernetes go client, what is a `clientset`?

It is defined in multiple places.

1. In the `client-go` package. https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/62b2cb756b8cea8fba00764ff123993eb44dbd48/kubernetes/clientset.go#L120
2. In the `kubernetes` package https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/80e344644e2b6222296f2f03551a8d0273c7cbce/pkg/client/clientset_generated/internalclientset/clientset.go#L64

The documentation says the same thing for both of them:

> Clientset contains the clients for groups. Each group has exactly
>   one version included in a Clientset.

This is confusing. What is a group?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Every resource type in Kubernetes (Pods, Deployments, Services and so on) is a member of an [API group](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#api-groups). These logically "group" the different types. Some examples of groups are

- `core`
- `extensions`
- `batch`
- `apps`
- `authentication`
- `autoscaling`

[Groups also contain versions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#api-versioning). Versions allow developers to introduce breaking changes to APIs, and manage them as they do. Some examples of versions inside a group

- `core/v1`
- `extensions/v1beta`
- `apps/v1beta1`
- `batch/v1`, `batch/v2alpha1` (notice the two versions inside the same group)
- `authentication/v1`, `authentication/v1beta1`
- `autoscaling/v1`, `autoscaling/v2alpha1`

So the client documentation is saying that it's creating a different client for every group.

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between the `clientset` in the `kubernetes` package and the `clientset` in the `client-go` package?

Comment: I don't really know if there is any difference

Comment: development is made in the kubernetes repository, changes are "mirrored" once a day to the client-go repository. The last paragraph "Contributing" in the readme of client-go gives a hint about that. Reason is afaik that client-go has always been in the k8s repo, but this way you can use it without needing to download/import all the k8s code.

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 7):

The description given by @Jose Armesto is correct, I would like to support it with a snippet.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

var kubeconfig string

func init() {
    // kubeconfig file parsing
    flag.StringVar(&kubeconfig, "kubeconfig", "", "path to Kubernetes config file")
    flag.Parse()
}

func main() {
    // create the config object from kubeconfig
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfig)

    // create clientset (set of muliple clients) for each Group (e.g. Core),
    // the Version (V1) of Group and Kind (e.g. Pods) so GVK.
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)

    ctx := context.Background()
    // executes GET request to K8s API to get pods 'cart' from 'prepayment' namespace
    pod, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("prepayment").Get(ctx, "cart", metav1.GetOptions{})
    fmt.Println("err: ", err)

    fmt.Println("pod: ", pod)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is actually the same for the two locations.  The Kubernetes project writes and manages all the code in a mono-repo (`kubernetes/kubernetes`), but then publishes the code they want other projects to consume to other repos to work better with the Go module system.  You can see a reference to the details of this publishing process [in this table](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/release-1.26#compatibility-matrix), though I'm not sure where the process is clearly documented.

BTW - you should consume this code through `k8s.io/client-go` as an import, which will fetch from the `github.com/kubernetes/client-go` repository.

Answer (score 1):

Following *jack_t*'s snippet, I'll add additional snippet regarding the **creation of `clientset` where the Go client** authenticate to the K8S API **from a pod running inside the cluster**:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
)

func main() {
    // creates the in-cluster config
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // creates the clientset
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    for {
        // get pods in all the namespaces by omitting namespace
        // Or specify namespace to get pods in particular namespace
        pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf("There are %d pods in the cluster\n", len(pods.Items))
    }
}
```

In this case, the `client-go` library will use the Service Account token that is mounted inside the Pod at the `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount` path when the `rest.InClusterConfig()` is used.

Reference - [here](https://Authenticating%20inside%20the%20cluster).